# How to use the SQL statement to transform the data from row record to column record

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I would like to transform the data from row records to column records by the SQL statement. The database structure shown as below:

The Table TestMethod is dynamic. User can add test records.

Table TestMethod

```
ID, TestMethod
1, TestA
2, TestB
3, TestC
4, Test..
5, Test..
6, Test..
```

Table A

```
ID, Code, TestMethod, RevNo, Value
1, A001, 1, 1, N
2, A002, 2, 1, N
3, A001, 3, 1, Y
4, A001, 1, 2, Y
...
...
...
```

How can i transform data to the following structure by SQL statement?

```
Code, RevNo, TESTA, TESTB, TESTC, TEST.., TEST.., TEST..
A001, 1, N, null, Y
A002, 1, null, N, null
A001, 2, Y, null, null
```

Please suggest some solution to me, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way of doing it using a cross tab:

```
use tempdb
create table temp(
    id int,
    Code varchar(10),
    TestMethod varchar(10),
    RevNo int,
    Value varchar(10)
)
insert into temp values
(1, 'A001', 'TESTA', 1, 'N'),
(2, 'A002', 'TESTB', 1, 'N'),
(3, 'A001', 'TESTC', 1, 'Y'),
(4, 'A001', 'TESTA', 2, 'Y')

select
    Code,
    RevNo,
    TestA = max(case when TestMethod = 'TESTA' then value end),
    TestB = max(case when TestMethod = 'TESTB' then value end),
    TestC = max(case when TestMethod = 'TESTC' then value end)
from temp
group by
    Code,
    revno

drop table temp
```

## UPDATE: USING A DYNAMIC CROSS TAB

```
use tempdb
create table TestMethod(
    Id int,
    TestMethod varchar(10)
)
create table TableA(
    Id int,
    Code varchar(10),
    TestMethodId int,
    RevNo int,
    Value varchar(10)
)
insert into TableA values
(1, 'A001', '1', 1, 'N'),
(2, 'A002', '2', 1, 'N'),
(3, 'A001', '3', 1, 'Y'),
(4, 'A001', '1', 2, 'Y'),
(5, 'A001', '2', 2, 'Y'),
(6, 'A002', '4', 1, 'Y'),
(7, 'A002', '5', 1, 'Y')
insert into TestMethod values
(1, 'TestA'),
(2, 'TestB'),
(3, 'TestC'),
(4, 'TestD'),
(5, 'TestE')

declare @sql1 varchar(4000) = ''
declare @sql2 varchar(4000) = ''
declare @sql3 varchar(4000) = ''

select @sql1 = 
'select
    a.Code
    ,a.RevNo
'
select @sql2 = @sql2 + 
'   ,max(case when a.TestMethodId  = ' + convert(varchar(10), Id) + ' then a.Value end) as [' + TestMethod + ']' + char(10)
from TestMethod 
order by TestMethod

select @sql3 = 
'from TableA a
inner join TestMethod m
    on m.id = a.TestMethodId
group by
    a.Code,
    a.RevNo
'

print (@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
exec (@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)

drop table TestMethod
drop table TableA
```